# Snap scroll flag only on toolbar in collapsing toolbar

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have a collapsing toolbar with a pinned toolbar, I want the collapsing toolbars free space to be allowed to scroll freely but the pinned toolbar to snap open or closed, my question is can this be achieved with scroll flags or will i need to create a custom layout behaviour or do some disabling and enabling of the flags based on the toolbars offset so to illustrate what i want here are some images,

Id like to allow this example of it being fully expanded

[image: fully expanded]

This would be an example of the scrolling freely free space (no snapping)

[image: half scroll]

This would be the collapsing toolbar fully scrolled and the pinned toolbar

[image: collapsed]

But I never want to allow this

[image: toolbar not snapping]

This is the pinned toolbar also being allowed to scroll freely (as its a child of the collapsing toolbar) I want just this toolbar to have a scroll flag of snap but in practice this doesn't work the toolbars flags are ignored

```
    <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
        app:titleEnabled="false"
        app:title=""
        app:titleTextColor="@android:color/transparent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@drawable/squareangle"
            app:titleTextColor="@android:color/transparent"
            app:title=""
            android:elevation="@dimen/large_margin_32dp"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:elevation="@dimen/large_margin_32dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="snap"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set scroll flags with

```
toolbarParams.setScrollFlags(SCROLL_FLAG_SCROLL | SCROLL_FLAG_ENTER_ALWAYS)
```

or by shifting as you can see [here](https://github.com/SmartToolFactory/Toolbar-Samples/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/smarttoolfactory/toolbarsamples/activity/Activity3CollapsingToolbarScrollFlags.kt), this is a sample playground to test Toolbar features.

Also you check AppbarLayout offset using

```
appbar.addOnOffsetChangedListener(AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener { appBarLayout, verticalOffset ->

    //Check if the view is collapsed
    if (abs(verticalOffset) >= appbar.totalScrollRange) {
        collapsingToolbar.title = "Collapsed"
    } else {
        collapsingToolbar.title = ""
    }

     // Change flags based on position of offset

})
```

I used this to create scrolling behavior over appbar for RecyclerView as can be seen [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SmartToolFactory/Toolbar-Samples/master/screenshots/ch7.gif)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Thracian i ended up with something like this

```
private fun handleAppBarSnapFlag() {
    binding.appBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener { appBarLayout, verticalOffset ->
        if (abs(verticalOffset) >= appBarLayout.totalScrollRange - getToolbarHeight()) {
            val toolbarParams = binding.collapsingToolbar.layoutParams as AppBarLayout.LayoutParams
            toolbarParams.scrollFlags = SCROLL_FLAG_SCROLL or SCROLL_FLAG_ENTER_ALWAYS or SCROLL_FLAG_ENTER_ALWAYS_COLLAPSED or SCROLL_FLAG_SNAP
        } else {
            val toolbarParams = binding.collapsingToolbar.layoutParams as AppBarLayout.LayoutParams
            toolbarParams.scrollFlags = SCROLL_FLAG_SCROLL or SCROLL_FLAG_ENTER_ALWAYS or SCROLL_FLAG_ENTER_ALWAYS_COLLAPSED
        }
    })
}
```